# sp_blitzCache results Memory grants

Tags: sql-server-2012, sp-blitzcache

I am running SQL Server 2012 and and using the March 2019 release of sp_blitzCache to analyze some slow running queries on the system.

I have executed the stored procedure with parameter @SortOrder = 'Reads' and found some queries reading tons of pages (in the millions) that need to be reduced.

The odd thing is that none of these queries are returning any information for the memory grant columns, they are all null.

Why is that we can have a query returned from sp_BlitzCache doing many reads and writes, but contain nulls for all memory grant columns?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 8):

Those columns only become available on SQL Server 2012 if it's patched up to [Service Pack 3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3072779/sql-server-2012-service-pack-3-release-information).

Specifically:

> Update for Dm_exec_query_stats DMV to track memory grants information
>   in SQL Server 2012

And KB [3107398](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3107398).

Just as an FYI, if you're [not on Service Pack 4, you're out of Microsoft support](https://sqlserverupdates.com/sql-server-2012-updates/).